# The difference between Lists as pairs and Lists as recursors in the Lambda Calculus

Tags: list, lambda-calculus

I understand that there are several ways to represent lists in the lambda calculus. Using pairs I can write a list as

(t1, (t2, (t3, NIL)))

which is equivalent to the lambda term `\f. f t1 (\f. t2 (\f. t3 NIL)))`

and perform operations such as

```
head = \l.l (\h.\t.h)
```

How do lists as recursors work and how would I write them down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List as recursors are "natural folds".

The ctors are looking like this:

```
nil  =               \add. \zero. zero
cons = \head. \tail. \add. \zero. add head (tail add zero)
```

After some optimization (inlining the bodies, beta/eta-reducing everything), the term

```
cons(1, cons(2, cons(3, nil)))
```

becomes the equivalent one

```
\add. \zero. add 1 (add 2 (add 3 zero))
```

As you can notice, the list waits for two ctor replacers (cons -> add, nil -> zero), and becomes a fold.

Applying a `(+)` and `0` will give us list sum, `(*)` and `1` - list product, `cons` again and some `tail` list will give us the `tail` appended to the back of initial list.

Head op is implemented like whis:

```
head = \l. \def. l (\x. \y. x) def
```

It takes a list and a default value to return if list is empty and returns the head.

The tail though is hard to implement and it will work with O(list-length).

Shortly, list as recursors are prepared folds.